# How to create Type Alias from dynamic strings

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-typescript

```
type MenuName = 'menu1' | 'menu2';
    
const [menuState, setMenuState] = useState({
    menu1: true,
    menu2: false,
});

<SubMenu handleToggle={() => handleToggle('menu1')} name="Item1" />;
<SubMenu handleToggle={() => handleToggle('menu2')} name="Item2" />;
```

Now MenuName is hardcoded with menu1 and menu2, but I want to add in type dynamic values from an array like

```
const menus = [
    {
        name: 'menu1',
        collapse: true,
    },
    {
        name: 'menu2',
        collapse: false,
    },
];
```

in this case :

```
type MenuName = menus.map(item=>item.name).join('|');
```

is a error Cannot find namespace 'menus'.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```js
const menus = [
    {
        name: 'menu1',
        collapse: true,
    },
    {
        name: 'menu2',
        collapse: false,
    },
] as const;


type MenuName = typeof menus[number]['name'];
// type MenuName = "menu1" | "menu2"
```

Notice the [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), see that `as const`, it is a way of telling TypeScript that this array is not going to change. If you don't do so, it will set `MenuName` as `string` because it can be ever increasing array with any string value could possibly be menu name.

Playground Link: https://tsplay.dev/Wk5DlN